# Nesting / escaping a f-string "=" (equal sign) expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting, f-string

Is it possible to escape a python f-string within a "=" expression? (new feature in Python 3.8)
For example I have the following expression:

```py
def double(x):
    return x * 2
some_int = 2

print(f'{double(some_int) = }')
```

Which prints:

```py
double(some_int) = 4
```

Is it possible to escape the `some_int` parameter in a way so that it prints:

```py
double(2) = 4
```

Or do I have to type the expression twice and concatenate the literal expression and result the old-fashioned way?

Comment: What would `=` even _mean_ in that context? Remember, assignment is a statement, not an expression, and an f-string needs to contain an _expression_ so its content returns a value that can be stringified and substituted.

Comment: ...which is to say, you really do need `f'double({some_int}) = {double(some_int)}'` (assuming you have a `double` function).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `=` in that context is a format specifier that causes the value to be output, preceded by the name of the variable and =. Handy for debugging. Define a suitable function `double()` and OP's code will run and show you `double(some_int) = 4`.

Comment: FWIW, you could do `print(f'{some_int = }; {double(some_int) = }')` instead, which prints `some_int = 2; double(some_int) = 4`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in the [What's New In Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging) document:

> Added an `=` specifier to f-strings. An f-string such as `f'{expr=}'` will
> expand to the **text** of the expression, an equal sign, then the
> representation of the evaluated expression.

So no, you can't do it that way(one shot) because the left side of `=` will become a string. Use traditional f-string interpolation:

```
print(f'double({some_int}) = {double(some_int)}')
```

Output:

`double(2) = 4`

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not run, however I assume you mean to do:

```
some_int = 2
print(f'double({some_int}) = {some_int*2}')
```

which prints:

```
double(2) = 4
```

Comment: @o11c I am running version 3.8.3

Comment: Oh I had to make a custom function called double

Comment: @TomMcLean I edited the question to include definition of `double`